# Source a tcsh script from bash

Tags: bash, tcsh

I'm trying to execute a tcsh script in a bash environment. My regular environment is tcsh so the following command works for me:

```
source /usr/scripts/my_setup -t abs
```

But I need to execute this command from some third party software which runs the commands on bash shell. This script should set an environment variable `$TMP`.
I already tried all the suggested solutions from the previous threads and they all do not work.
What I tried:

1. `tcsh -c "source /usr/scripts/my_setup -t abs ; exec bash"`
2. `tcsh -c "source /usr/scripts/my_setup -t abs ; bash"`
3. The following steps:

   ```
   echo "tcsh -c 'source /usr/scripts/my_setup -t abs'" > setup
   chmod a+x setup
   source setup
   ```

They all fail. And I understand why (everytime I use `tcsh` it opens a new shell). But I can't seem to understand how to source a tcsh script from bash.

Comment: Can't be done. `source`ing a script *runs it in the current interpreter*. bash can't run a tcsh script any more than Python can run a Perl script.

Comment: ...the answers you're pulling from will pick up *environment* variables your tcsh script sets, but not *local* variables. (They're not sourcing the csh script in bash in any meaningful way, but are sourcing the csh script *in a new copy of csh*, and then starting a new copy of bash from the copy of csh that previously ran those commands).